# Как установить модуль webpage phantomjs?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Чтобы этот код не приводил к ошибке.
В npm модуль webpage совсем другой.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
```

Comment: Чем это принципиально отличается от кода в вопросе?